# GORM one-to-many cascade update orphan still has the relationship

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I am pretty new to GORM and hibernate and needs a little help on how to remove entity from one-to-many relationship and persist it into database.

Here are my domain classes:

```
package helloworld

class ClassRoom {
    String name
    static hasMany = [students: Student]

    static constraints = {
        students nullable: true
    }
}
class Student {
    String name

    static belongsTo = [classroom: ClassRoom]

    static constraints = {
        classroom nullable: true
    }
}
```

And the test case:

```
package helloworld

import grails.test.mixin.Mock
import grails.test.mixin.TestFor
import spock.lang.Specification

/**
* See the API for {@link grails.test.mixin.domain.DomainClassUnitTestMixin} for usage instructions
*/
@TestFor(ClassRoom)
@Mock([Student, ClassRoom])
class ClassRoomSpec extends Specification {

    void "test deletion"() {
        given:
            def s1 = new Student(name: 'Student 1')
            def s2 = new Student(name: 'Student 2')

            def c1 = new ClassRoom(name: 'Classroom 1')
            c1.addToStudents(s1)
            c1.addToStudents(s2)
            c1.save()

            def classroom1Students = Student.findAllByClassroom c1
        expect:
            classroom1Students.size() == 2
            ClassRoom.findByName('Classroom 1').students.size() == 2
            classroom1Students.get(0).name == 'Student 1'
            classroom1Students.get(1).name == 'Student 2'
            c1.students.size() == 2
        when:
            c1.students.collect().each {
                c1.removeFromStudents(it)
//                it.save()
            }
            c1.save()
        then:
            c1.students.size() == 0
            ClassRoom.findByName('Classroom 1').students.size() == 0

            def class1StudentsNow = Student.findAllByClassroom c1
            class1StudentsNow.size() == 0

    }
}
```

I can see the `c1` domain object is saved correctly without any `Students` associated to it, which is good.

However the `Students` domain class is not saved and still have `classroom` attribute set unless `it.save()` line is uncommitted out, which is not what I expected as I assume GORM/hibernate can handle such cases when doing updates but I am ok with that as well since it might be hard for GORM/hibernate to do that as the `Students` are removed from `c1`.

What I **DON'T** expect is that `calss1StudentsNow` still has a size of 2, which means there are still a association between `c1` and `s1`/`s2`. Although `c1.student.size()` is 0 now and inspect on `Student.list()` shows that all `Students` now don't have a `classroom` attribute when `it.save()` is uncommitted out.

I guess there might be something wrong with the association table, but I am unable to find out what is wrong.

Also I noticed there is a customised setting to control the cascade setting, like:

```
static mapping = {
    chapters(cascade:"all-delete-orphan")
}
```

But I don't really want `Student` instance to be removed as they may go to another `ClassRoom` instead and I want to keep them in the database so that I can associate them to other `ClassRoom` instance later, rather than deleting them then creating them again, losing history information.

I am using grails 3.2.0 with h2 in memory database for the test now.

Comment: If a classroom can exist without any associated students, and a student can exist without any associated classrooms, then your model is insufficient. You need a join table between classrooms and students. Classroom -> ClassroomStudent <- Student. To remove a student from a classroom, you just delete the proper ClassroomStudent record.

Comment: Thanks @railsdog your point is valid. If grails/gorm is not clever enough to take care of the join then I may have to go for a explict join table `ClassroomStudeng`.